# Arranging items from a mongoDB object into a list top to bottom with Angular.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have a simple todo list app with node.js, angular.js, mongoDB and mongoose as the object modeling. I want to be able to have the newly added item be insert on the top of the list an not the bottom. I thought this was an Angular.js prepending issue, but upon further reading it is because the data is being stored in an object. Is there a way to sort it from top to bottom? Is it a mongoDB issue or Angular? Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you need more code I can provide it. Again thank you.

The HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Vote</td>
                <td>Song</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <td><button class="btn btn-success icon-thumbs-up" alt="Up vote this song if you like it.">Vote</button></td>
                <td>{{ todo.text }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-times" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)" alt="Remove the song if you need to make an edit and then add it back."></button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

API service

```
// each function returns a promise object 
.factory('Todos', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/todos');
        },
        create : function(todoData) {
            return $http.post('/api/todos', todoData);
        },
        delete : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id);
        }
    }
});
```

Some of the Angular

```
// CREATE ==================================================================
    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;

        // validate the formData to make sure that something is there
        // if form is empty, nothing will happen
        if ($scope.formData.text != undefined) {

            // call the create function from our service (returns a promise object)
            Todos.create($scope.formData)

                // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new todos
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                    $scope.todos = data; // assign our new list of todos
                });
        }
    };

 // create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    todos.unshift(todo);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});
```

Object model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
text : String,
done : Boolean
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check what the order is coming back from Mongo, place `<pre>{{todos}}</pre>` in your view html and see if they are sorted how you want.  Then you should know if is Mongo or Angular issue.

For a simple fix you can add default date in mongoose schema:

```
time: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

Then in Angular view add [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) clause to the ngRepeat directive to sort this field

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: '-time'">
```

This way in your controller you can just worry about get the data itself and view will properly sort whatever is there automatically when it updates.  Also you could give user toggle button to sort by newest or oldest

Comment: Going to try this out right now. I shall let you know how it goes and give you a bump if it works!

Comment: @aaronsil It seems to be repeating it in a random order.

Comment: I got it working. I did the orderBy '-_id' and that works. ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: '-_id'" Your solution did help for sure!

Comment: OK cool!  I think also with schema if you use `default: new Date()` instead of `Date.now` then you can sort by date.  `Date.now` give # of millis so could have been sorting numerically hence the random order.

Comment: I had trouble by specifiying todo.time in orderBy: ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: '-todo.time'". Might be helpful to somebody.

Comment: @mgalic, the property name (`'-time'`) is all you need, object name (`todo`) isn't required

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly recommend discarding the `Todo.find` in your post method. Instead just return the `todo` in the callback from server-side `Todo.create` in your post method.

Second, don't reassign `$scope.todos` in client-side `Todos.create`. If you just send back the one object you posted, you'll be able to use `todos.unshift(todo)` client-side and place the newest todo at the top of the list.

Lastly, you need to add some kind of ordinal to your todo mongoose schema and use a sort to make sure the order is what you prefer when the list of todos is serverd.

Here's your server-side code returning the newly inserted todo.

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    res.json(todo);

});
```

here's your client-side code inserting the response from the post back into the todos array
    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;

```
    // validate the formData to make sure that something is there
    // if form is empty, nothing will happen
    if ($scope.formData.text != undefined) {

        // call the create function from our service (returns a promise object)
        Todos.create($scope.formData)

            // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new todos
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                $scope.todos.unshift(data); // assign our new list of todos
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: It keeps saying todo is not defined. I must not be returning it correctly. Where to a write return todo in the server side Todo.create?

Comment: Also if I remove Todo.find it doesn't show the added item in the list until you refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you. Well it half works. It is putting it at the top of the list and posting the text, but now the text is not displaying on the front end. I can only see it in my object.

Comment: Also after refresh it all goes back down to the bottom of the list. I really appreciate the time you are spending on this. All of it helps.

Comment: To fix the order, you need to add a sort server-side on your get request.